# use python to loop through values in dictionary to change value based on key

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary with 100 entries like this..

```
d = {
    'entrenched': ['the Internet is firmly entrenched in our lives.'], 
    'profoundly': ['racism is profoundly entrenched within different social spheres.']
}
```

I want to loop through the dictionary and replace one of the words in the value based on the key.

The output should look like this:

```
d = {
    'entrenched': ['the Internet is firmly en...   in our lives.'], 
    'profoundly': ['racism is pr...   entrenched within different social spheres.']
}
```

I tried this code

```
for k,v in d.items():    
    for word in v:
        if word == k:
            gapped_word = word[1:]+ '...'
            final_sentence = v.replace(word,gapped_word )
            print(final_sentence)
```

but got no output. I'm also not sure what the final line should be if instead of printing I am replacing the original value with the adjusted one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each dictionary item maps from a string to a list you should iterate the items in that list. Then, for each of those items, perform the replacing. In addition, notice that you do not have to split the sentence into words, but simply perform the operation over the entire sentence.

```
final_d = { k: [item.replace(k, k[:2]+"...") for item in v] for k, v in d.items()}
```

Where the value of `final_d` is are desired:

```
{'entrenched': ['the Internet is firmly en... in our lives.'],
 'profoundly': ['racism is pr... entrenched within different social spheres.']}
```

Comment: I tried the code and got "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'"   I tried  to convert to string with str ......final_d = { k: [item.replace(k, k[:2]+"...") for str(item) in v] for k, v in d.items()} and it stalled. final_d = { k: [str(item.replace(k, k[:2]+"...")) for item in v] for k, v in d.items()} and got the same error

Comment: @JohnAiton - The code above does not throw an exception for the dictionary as posted in question. No need to convert item to string - it is already a string (and that is also not correct syntax). Also the second code you posted in the comment runs fine)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex` like below:

```
import re

d = {
    'entrenched': ['the Internet is firmly entrenched in our lives.'], 
    'profoundly': ['racism is profoundly entrenched within different social spheres.'],
    'firm': ['the Internet is firmly entrenched in our lives.'], 
    'firmly': ['the Internet is firmly entrenched in our lives.'], 
}

{k : [re.sub(fr'\b{k}\b',  f'{k[:2]}...', s)   for s in v] for k,v in d.items()}
```

Output

```
{'entrenched': ['the Internet is firmly en... in our lives.'],
 'profoundly': ['racism is pr... entrenched within different social spheres.'],
 'firm': ['the Internet is firmly entrenched in our lives.'],
 'firmly': ['the Internet is fi... entrenched in our lives.']}
```

Comment: This would also replace `firmly` with `fi...ly` if the key is `firm`.

Answer (score 0):

- `for word in v:` goes by whole sentences; to get word by word, we need to either:

  - use `for sentence in v:` then  `for word in sentence.split()`; or
  - use `for sentence in v:` then `if k in sentence`
- To assign it back, we need to replace or assign into the list; to get the index to assign into the array, we can use `for i, sentence in enumerate(v)` then later `v[i] = final_sentence`

In general, be careful about modifying the dictionary while you're iterating over it; changing an existing entry should be fine, but anything else can mess up the iteration. If you need to make more extensive changes, build a new dictionary with the result (or build a list of changes to apply, then do that in a separate loop).

Comment: Note that `v` is a list of strings, so need to nest loops another level.

Comment: Right; I missed that...

Comment: I did have v.split(' ') before but it gave me  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'   when I just tried v.split() it gave me the same AttributeError

Comment: Yeah, as pointed out in the first comment, we need to nest the loops another level

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values for your dictionary will always be a list containing a single string (your sentence). You could use the code below:

```
d = {key:[value[0].replace(key, key[:2] + "...")] for key, value in d.items()}
```